# Web Form not working php/html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im having trouble customizing this landing page forms. I have changed the ids and classes where i see fit. I also updated the php config files to do the same. I have not however touched any of the js. I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Theme Starz">

    <link href="assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">

    <title>We Buy Homes for Cash</title>

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navigation" data-offset="90" class="slider-has-video">
<!-- Wrapper -->
<section id="home"></section>
<div class="wrapper">
   <!-- <div class="navigation fixed navigation-hide">
       <div class="container">
           <header class="navbar" id="top" role="banner">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
                   <div class="navbar-brand nav" id="brand">
                       <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="brand"></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
             <!--  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#features">Why Condio</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#features-boxes">Features</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </nav>--><!-- /.navbar collapse
           </header><!-- /.navbar
       </div><!-- /.container
   </div><!-- /.navigation -->

    <section id="slider">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <div id="loading-icon"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i></div>
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide video">
                    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/34741214?title=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- /.slides -->
        </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
        <div class="slider-banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h2>Turn your equity into immediate cash!</h2>
                            <figure class="subtitle">Your might me sitting on a gold mine without knowing it.</figure>
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
                        </div><!-- /.title -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-md-8 -->
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-slider-wrapper">
                            <header>
                                <h3>Get your Cash Offer</h3>
                                <h1>within a couple of days. </h1>
                            </header>
                            <hr>
                            <form role="form" id="form-slider">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Your Name<em>*</em></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lettercode">Reference Code<em>  <br>** Lower right of the letter you recieved**</em></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lettercode" name="lettername" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phone">Your Phone<em>*</em></label>
                                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="contact-form-phone" name="contact-form-phone" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div id="form-slider-status"></div>
                                    <button type="submit" id="form-slider-submit" class="btn btn-default">Make me an Offer!</button>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            </form><!-- /#form-slider -->
                            <figure>*Required Fields</figure>
                        </div><!-- /.form-slider-wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div><!-- /.slider-banner -->
    </section><!-- /#slider -->
    <section id="features" class="block">
        <div class="container">
            <header><h3>What can you do with your money?</h3></header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="features-list">
                        <li>Invest in your retirement.</li>
                        <li>Pay off debt.</li>
                        <li>Fund your emergency fund.</li>
                        <li>Start a college fund for your children.</li>
                        <li>Invest in immediate annuities and <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;live off the interest</li>
                    </ul><!-- /.features-list -->
                </div><!-- /.col-md-8 -->
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="image-carousel">
                        <div class="image-carousel-slide">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                    <a href="assets/img/box-image-02.jpg" class="image-popup">
                                        <img src="assets/img/features-slide-01.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                                    <h4>Many of our clients have had success with our buying process.</h4>
                                    <p>We've helped many clients get the offer that they need. Some of our clients use the cash to supplement their income others use it to invest in their future. Whatever the case. Rest assured, we can help!</p>
                        <a href="#home" class="btn roll">Get an offer NOW!</a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.row -->
                        </div><!-- /.image-carousel-slide -->
                        <!-- <div class="image-carousel-slide">
                           <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                   <a href="http://vimeo.com/24506451" class="video-popup">
                                       <img src="assets/img/features-slide-02.jpg" alt="">
                                   </a>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                                   <h4>Nullam in nisl vitae elit sollicitudin bibendum in quis magna. Integer commodo velit nec orci</h4>
                                   <p>Nullam in nisl vitae elit sollicitudin bibendum in quis magna. Integer commodo velit nec orci aliquam congue.
                                       Pellentesque euismod ac erat et dapibus.</p>
                                   <a href="http://vimeo.com/24506451" class="btn btn-framed video-popup">Play Video <span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span></a>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>--><!-- /.image-carousel-slide -->
                       <!-- <div class="image-carousel-slide">
                           <a href="assets/img/box-image-02.jpg" class="image-popup">
                               <img src="assets/img/features-slide-03.jpg" alt="">
                           </a>
                       </div>
                   </div> -->
                </div><!-- /.col-md-8 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#features .block -->
    <section id="features-boxes" class="block background-color-grey-light">
        <div class="container">
            <header><h3>How it works.</h3></header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="feature-box">
                        <header>
                            <img src="assets/img/icon-01.png" alt="">
                            <h4>Step Number One</h4>
                        </header>
                        <p>
Our representatives will take a few moments to understand your situation. Depending on your situation we might offer to have a representative to your home and evaluate your home in person.                </p>
                    </div><!-- /.feature-box -->
                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="feature-box">
                        <header>
                            <img src="assets/img/icon-02.png" alt="">
                            <h4>Step Number Two</h4>
                        </header>
                        <p>
Our in person evaluation takes only a few minutes. We will be looking for needed repairs and anything that will increase the value of your home
                        </p>
                    </div><!-- /.feature-box -->
                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="feature-box">
                        <header>
                            <img src="assets/img/icon-03.png" alt="">
                            <h4>Step Number Three</h4>
                        </header>
                        <p>
Typically it takes 48 hours to get a cash offer from the time our representative evaluates your property. You will be in escrow as soon as you accept the offer.
                        </p>
                    </div><!-- /.feature-box -->
                </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#features-boxes .block -->
    <section id="boxes" class="block background-color-grey-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box" data-scroll-reveal="enter top and move 30px">
                <div class="image width-50 pull-left">
                    <img src="assets/img/box-image-01.jpg" class="top-50" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="description width-50">
                    <div class="description-wrapper">
                        <header><h3>Foreclosure, Divorce, Probate, or any situation.</h3></header>
                        <p>The process can be long and tedious. You have the option to take the golden parachute. Take the rest of your money and move on to the next part of your life. Get cash in hand and move forward.</p>
                        <a href="#home" class="btn roll">Get an offer NOW!</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.description -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
            <div class="box" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom and move 30px">
                <div class="description width-30 pull-left">
                    <div class="description-wrapper top-180">
                        <header><h3>Rehad Needed or Brand New</h3></header>
                        <p>We buy houses that are practically destroyed all the way to brand new. Our representative will visit your home and evaluate the condition of your home. All offers are based on the condition of the property and the market value.</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.description -->
                <div class="image width-70">
                    <img src="assets/img/box-image-02.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.box -->
           <!-- <section class="video" data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 30px">
               <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/34741214?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </section> -->
            <div class="box with-empty-space" data-scroll-reveal="enter right and move 30px">
                <div class="width-40 pull-left">
                    <div class="empty-space"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="description width-60">
                    <div class="description-wrapper">
                        <header><h3>How long will it take to get an offer

</h3></header>
                        <p>Typically it takes 48 hours to get a cash offer from the time our representative evaluates your property. You will be in escrow as soon as you accept the offer.</p>
                        <a href="#home" class="btn roll">Get an offer NOW!</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.description -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#boxes -->

    <section id="testimonials" class="block" data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 30px">
        <div class="container">
            <header class="section-title"><h3>Testimonials</h3></header>
            <div class="owl-carousel testimonials-carousel">
                <blockquote class="testimonial">
                    <figure>

                    </figure>
                    <aside class="cite">
                        <p>I had a great experience with webuyhomesonline.org they came to see my home and a day later they offered me 230k! I was extatic to take that money straight to the bank. Now I don't stress about my future!</p>
                        <footer>M. Navaro</footer>
                    </aside>
                </blockquote>
                <blockquote class="testimonial">
                    <figure>

                    </figure>
                    <aside class="cite">
                        <p>We were going through some hard times when I received a letter. We needed the money so we called and a week later they have us a cash offer. It was more than we expected. We were so happy!</p>
                        <footer>Sergio Pozar</footer>
                    </aside>
                </blockquote>
            </div><!-- /.testimonials-carousel -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section><!-- /#testimonials -->
    <hr>
   <!-- <section id="logos" class="block">
       <div class="container">
           <header><h3>Our Other Successful Projects</h3></header>
           <div class="logos">
               <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="assets/img/logo-partner-01.png" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="assets/img/logo-partner-02.png" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="assets/img/logo-partner-03.png" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="assets/img/logo-partner-04.png" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="assets/img/logo-partner-05.png" alt=""></a></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>-->
    <section id="contact" class="block background-color-grey-dark has-dark-background">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4 empty-space">
                   <!--  <header><h3>Our Agent</h3></header>
                   <section class="agent">
                       <div class="agent-id">
                           <img src="assets/img/agent.jpg">
                           <div class="agent-wrapper">
                               <h4>John Doe</h4>
                               <p>Aliquam sit amet augue non arcu mollis suscipit. Quisque scelerisque</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="agent-contact">
                           <div><strong>Phone:</strong> (123) 456 789 000</div>
                           <div><strong>E-mail:</strong> <a href="#">john.doe@example.com</a></div>
                           <div><strong>Skype:</strong> John Doe</div>
                       </div>
                   </section> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <header><h3>Contact Form</h3></header>
                    <form role="form" id="form-contact" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-form-name">Your Name<em>*</em></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-form-name" name="contact-form-name" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-form-phone">Your Phone Number<em>*</em></label>
                                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="contact-form-phone" name="contact-form-phone" required>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-form-message">Reference Code and, Message <em>*</em></label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="contact-form-message" rows="6" name="contact-form-message" required></textarea>
                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-large" id="form-contact-submit">Send a Message</button>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        <div id="form-status"></div>
                    </form><!-- /#form-contact -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <figure>WeBuyHomesOnline.org</figure>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- end Wrapper -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scrollReveal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>


***********START contact.php**************
<?php
$name = $_POST['contact-form-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-form-phone'];
$message = $_POST['contact-form-message'];

$to = 'sid@agentmarketingcloud.com, mrisidro@outlook.com';
$subject = 'You have a New Lead ';

$body = "";
$body .= "Name: ";
$body .= $name;
$body .= "\n\n";

$body .= "";
$body .= "Message: ";
$body .= $message;
$body .= "\n";

$headers = 'From: ' .$phone . "\r\n";

//$headers = 'From: noreply@domain.com' . "\r\n";

//$body .= "";
//$body .= "Email: ";
//$body .= $email;
//$body .= "\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo '<span id="valid">Your Email was sent!</span>';
}else{
echo '<span id="invalid">Your message cannot be sent.</span>';
}
***********END contact.php**************

***********START subscribe.php**************

<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['lettercode'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$to = 'sid@agentmarketingcloud.com, lotuslistings@gmail.com';
$subject = 'You Have new lead!';

$body = "";
$body .= "Name: ";
$body .= $name;
$body .= "\n\n";

$body .= "";
$body .= "Reference: ";
$body .= $lettercode;
$body .= "\n\n";

$body .= "";
$body .= "Phone no.: ";
$body .= $phone;
$body .= "\n";

$headers = 'From: ' .$lettercode . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo '<span id="valid">Thank you for your subscription! We will notice you as soon as possible</span>';
}else{
echo '<span id="invalid">Something gets wrong. Please try again.</span>';
}

***********END subscribe.php**************
```

Comment: See error code live.. http://webuyhomesonline.org/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified link to your PHP code in action parameter.. 
Try using this

```
<form role="form" id="form-contact" method="post" action="subscribe.php">
```

**And FYI:** mail doesn't work on localhost unless you have a mail server installed on your machine.